# Ajax Search Function not fire in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm going to implement some search functionality. But I'm still failing to pass `searchString` to the controller.

```
@model IEnumerable<ASF.NWS.Entities.DX.News>        

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "News", new { searchString = searchString }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "showNews", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnFailure = "error" }))
{
    <input type="text" id="searchString" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString) // <-- searchString comes null
{
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give you input a name attribute

```
<input type="text" name="searchString" id="searchString" />
```

Its the `name` and `value` attributes of each control that are sent when a form is submitted (the `id` attribute is probably not required unless you are using javascript to access the element)

You also need to remove `new { searchString = searchString }` from the `Ajax.BeginForm` helper. Your trying to set a route value, but `searchString` will be undefined

Comment: im getting error here also  new { searchString = searchString }

Comment: Didn't notice that. You need to remove it